# How to extract numeric part from an alphanumeric string in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

ex:- 40587125sdaasdgasd@#

How can i separate numeric part from above string and add 1 into this numeric part again concat into this alphanumeric string.

OUTPUT:

```
40587125+1= 40587126
40587126sdaasdgasd@#
```

All have to be dynamically.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick(tested on `MySQL 5.7`) :

```
select @testValue := "40587125sdaasdgasd@#";

select @newValue := CAST(@testValue AS UNSIGNED);

select REPLACE(@testValue, @newValue, @newValue + 1);
```

You can find the sample, here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fDXa8QRDKNYSHDNsKEtyD6/0

Comment: It's very straight forward, the first line is you original value, the second line is a cast that took the numeric part and store that value on @newValue, and the third one, you replace the number on the original value with the new +1 value

Comment: If i put character in front of this string its not working.